# Error en la conexión de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

resulta que tengo un problema ya que estoy realizando un crud sencillo con php y mysql, usando xampp como servidor, pasa que iba bien hasta el momento que tube que realizar la inserción de datos a la base de datos segun yo realice la la instrucción sql bien y me dispuse a realizarle una prueba para saber si funcionaba y siempre que intentaba agregar datos me arrojaba la opcion de query fallido, adjunto imagen.

por favor ignoren que está comentariado lo hice para probar otras cosas pero no funciono.

[image: por favor ignoren que está comentariado lo hice para probar otras cosas pero no funciono]

Comment: Puedes hacer un `mysqli_error(link)` así te va a devolver el error en la consulta, o un `mysqli_erno(link)` para ver el código de error

Comment: Por favor agrega el contenido de conexion.php y especifica el error que te devuelve PHP.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Agrega el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Te recomiendo que el query lo ejecutes directamente en phpmyadmin (si es lo que estas usando) agrégale valores de prueba para verificar que realice la inserción correctamente, aunque el query lo veo bien, tal vez es la conexión, agrega la conexión a tu pregunta, igual verifica el nombre de la tabla, de la bd, y los parámetros de conexión como usuario y contraseña